# Weird behaviour of compiler

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I have simple program

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    A(){}
    void print(int i)
    {
        cout << "A::print: " << i << endl;
    }
};

struct B : public A
{
    B() : A() {}
    virtual void print(int i) {};
};

struct C : public B
{
    C() : B() {}
    virtual void print(int i)
    {
        cout << "C::print: " << i << endl;
    }
};



void main()
{
    A* ca = new C();
    C* cc = new C();
    ca->print(1);
    cc->print(1);
}
```

And I cannot understand why my compiler (msvc2008) does not show any warnings. Maybe I do not understand mechanics of virtual functions? In fact, we have wrong redefinition of method, which depends on used pointer

Comment: Sorry, right spelling is compiler

Comment: Just edit your post instead of leaving a comment.

Comment: I don't write much C++, but I'm failing to see what you think is a problem with your code. Can you elaborate  (by editing the question please)?

Comment: It's normal behavior. Due to the inheritance a `A*` pointer can hold a `C*` pointer. What is the output you expect/get?

Comment: Which warning would you expect, exactly?

Comment: For example, compiler has to say, that we have potentially dangerous redefinition in this case (or to forbid usage of print method from A class)

Comment: Since it _doesn't_ emit a warning, that suggests that maybe it shouldn't. So you will have to explain why _you_ instead think that it should, because we do not have that information.

Comment: I thought that virtual print method in A class, is more suitable, otherwise it is dangerous usage

Comment: Yes, I do. I just do not understand, why this redefinition is possible

Comment: This is only a problem if you intended to have the function in `A` be virtual, and C++11 has introduced `override` (available in VS2008) which catches that immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class A defines `print` as not virtual and it's allowed.
No warnings here, it's valid code. You're saying that print of A is not virtual, the function that has to be executed is `A::print`

Answer (score 1):

> In fact, we have wrong redefinition of method, which depends on used pointer

It's only "wrong" according to your intentions, which the compiler cannot know.

The code as written is perfectly valid. Virtual dispatch is opt-in, and you've not opted-in.

Comment: Virtual dispatch is opt-in, and you've not opted-in -  what do you mean, compiler has options, related with this case?

Comment: @АлександрЛысенко No. It just means that if a function is not marked as `virtual`, it will not be virtual. There's nothing wrong with `A::print` being non-virtual, then hidden by `B::print` which is virtual, which is then overridden by `C::print`.